# how to get last item from cart magento

Tags: magento, cart

need to get the last item name,image, url and price.

```
$session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item)
{
$productid = $item->getProductId();
$productname = $item->getName();
$productqty = $item->getQty();
}
```

this is working, but I can’t get the image and url.

Comment: you sure you can't just access it by $item->getProduct()->getName(); instead of doing a full load() ?

Comment: on your Collection you can call $collection->getFirstItem(); for another solution. (descending it first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections don't usually load the whole Object, you need to re-load the object to get the other data you need:

```
$session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
// Get all items, including child / hidden items
foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $productname = $_prod->getName();
    $productqty = $_prod->getQty();
    // Now you have a full loaded Product Object.
}
// Visible items only
foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $productname = $_prod->getName();
    $productqty = $_prod->getQty();
    // Now you have a full loaded Product Object.
}
```

Comment: thank you! I have now another problem. I need to get all this parameters, but for the configurable product (the parent) .

Comment: then use `getAllVisibleItems` instead of `getAllItems`